# Getting error while running test class-System.NoAccessException: Set up My Domain to access this page

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, mydomain

i am into the situation where from Developer console my test class is getting passed but from UI -its with error **'System.NoAccessException: Set up My Domain to access this page.'**

Please suggest.[image]

From here its getting failed
From Dev console its getting pass[image]

My domain has setup already

Comment: Maybe set up my domain? What do you mean  that your unit test is not passing from the UI? For example lightning components wont be available without setting up my domain

Comment: From Apex class when i Am running test class its failing ,but from developer console its getting passed

Comment: Could you provide part of the code that is failing?